# Connecting a 1 1/4" bathroom sink tailpipe to a 2" wall drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, plumbing-fixture

I'm trying to replace a sink, including a new drain fitting.  The existing p-trap seems to be 2" ABS, as pictured.

The 90-degree elbow that connects to the pipe leading into the wall is threaded, with a nut connecting to the p-trap.  I have found a 2-inch ABS p-trap which appears to use the same threading, so I think I can unscrew the nut, leaving the elbow in place, and replace the rest of the system out to the new drain.

The problem is that the new drain has a standard 1-1/4" tailpipe, and the replacement p-trap ends in a 2" hub.  I can't seem to find an adapter that goes into the 2" hub on one side and provides a 1-1/4" slip joint on the other side.  I think the 2" side should be a "spigot" fitting, but nothing shows up on the usual home improvement stores for `2" spigot x 1-1/4" slip`, or even `2" spigot x 1-1/2" slip` (assuming I can find a reducer gasket).

(As you can see, the existing connection is a pretty rough bodge-job using some kind of mix of putty and adhesives, and I'd like to avoid repeating that mistake.)

[image: complete drain]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drop the 2" to 1-1/2" at the wall with a reducer and stub and terminate with a trap adapter (all cemented, and ABS in your case). That's a more standard size for a sink, and most trap kits come with compression nuts and washers that will fit.

[image]

If you'd rather not add parts, you can get no-hub adapters to suit. I'd rather have hard parts, though.

[image]

Comment: Just to be clear, in this case I would be cutting the 2" horizontal pipe, between the wall and the 90 degree elbow, then installing the white adapter in your first photo with solvent, correct?  I actually have a bagged 1-1/2" full kit on hand but was trying to avoid having to cut anything to install it.  If cutting is the best answer, though, I suppose I'll give it a try :D

Comment: Also: your first pic appears to be a K01820C.  The listing I found says it's 2" both sides, though in the pic it sure looks like it's reducing on the slip side.  If you have a part number or link handy that's definitely 2" hub / 1.5" slip, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Don't install white anything. You have ABS, so buy ABS parts. Yes, the reducer, pipe stub, and trap adapter will be permanent, cemented installations. Cutting is easy and the right move. The images are examples, not precise specifications. Use common sense. :) I'm not a parts counter. Get your own numbers. :)

Comment: Hah! More than fair.  I thought you were suggesting a combined trap-adapter-plus-reducer, wasn't finding anything, so thought I'd missed something important.  Will find separate reducer and trap-adapter.  (P-trap kit is PVC but will be compression-fit to trap adapter; that's OK, right?)

Comment: The trap kit is likely _polyethylene_, not PVC. That's fine. You can connect dissimilar materials with compression fittings.

Comment: @JamesB I second the first suggestion.   It's easy to do, and a benefit of using a polyethylene trap kit are 1) You get a free cleanout simply by unscrewing it, 2) you get *two* slip joints, on on the sink tail piece and the other on the arm after the trap.  This gives you a *ton* of leeway in aligning the pieces without stressing the joints 3) they are CHEAP, if they get disgusting or leaky you can easily replace them with no tools.   A 1-1/4" trap kit will fit the new tail piece and will include an adapting washer to fit the 1-1/2" trap adapter that you glue in.

Comment: Just got back from the store.  I've got an "all purpose" cement (red jar) and PVC reducer and trap adapter. The guy in the plumbing aisle was pretty adamant that cementing PVC to ABS wouldn't cause problems, and that the no-prime solution was fine since it's not under pressure.  Not going to install today, if PVC-to-ABS is a huge problem I can return but honestly ABS parts have been nearly impossible to find.  The local places don't carry it and at the big chains most parts are online-only.

Comment: No, that's fine. I just didn't expect you to have any trouble finding ABS. As long as the cement is appropriate, all good.

Comment: When I was helping my in-laws install a new vanity we ran into a similar problem.  1.25" tailpiece on the vanity, and 2" pipe on the wall.  We could NOT find any kind of way to convert a 1.25" trap to anything bigger than 1.5".  We ended up using a converted on the wall pipe to get to a 1.5" elbow, and one of these to get from the 1.25" tailpiece to 1.5": https://www.homedepot.com/p/Fernco-1-1-2-in-x-1-1-4-in-PVC-Drain-Trap-PFT-150/100372301

Comment: As I mentioned most 1-1/4" trap kits will interface with a 1-1/2" drain pipe without extra adapters. It's just a matter of using the right nut and washer.

Comment: My 1.5" trap adapter included a washer for securing a 1.5" tailpipe, plus a removeable "nested" washer that snaps together with the first one to fit 1.25" pipe.